# Spring Boot ThymeLeaf Not Loading HTML

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-thymeleaf

I have a Java and Maven project in which I have the following controller (src/main/java/com/example/romannumerals/controller/RomanNumeralController):

```
@RestController
public class RomanNumeralController {
    @GetMapping("/roman-numerals/{number}")
    public String RomanNumeral(@PathVariable int number){
        return RomanNumeralsService.numberToNumeral(number);
    }

    @GetMapping("/roman-numerals")
    public String RomanNumeral() {
        return "roman-numeral";
    }
}
```

I some HTML (src/main/resources/templates/roman-numeral.html) that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>From Numbers to Roman Numerals</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
Roman Numerals
</body>
</html>
```

I expected this HTML to be displayed when I called the method on the controller that has no parameter.  Instead, I get the string "roman-numeral" printed to the screen.  Am I doing something wrong?  I thought Thymeleaf would recognise that I want to display the HTML page with that name instead of the string being displayed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace @RestController with @Controller. @RestController will make the returned object the HTTP response body.

Answer (score 0):

Changing @RestController to @Controller worked for me!